# Access appsettings.json in class library

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I search for a solution to access the appsettings.json within a class library. I have a ASP.NET Core web application which depends on a class library. In this class library I must read some properties from the appsettings.json.

Are there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use Options

It's fairly simple to use. Check this article. it's well explained [Src](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration)

1/ Create your Options class

```
namespace UsingOptions.Models
{
    public class MyOptions
    {
        public MyOptions()
        {
            // Set default value.
            Option1 = "value1_from_ctor";
        }
        public string Option1 { get; set; }
        public int Option2 { get; set; } = 5;
    }
}
```

2/ Configure it in the ConfigureServices method (In startup.cs)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Adds services required for using options.
    services.AddOptions();

    // Register the IConfiguration instance which MyOptions binds against.
    **services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration);**

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

3/ Inject IOptions into your controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyOptions _options;

    public HomeController(IOptions<MyOptions> optionsAccessor)
    {
        _options = optionsAccessor.Value;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var option1 = _options.Option1;
        var option2 = _options.Option2;
        return Content($"option1 = {option1}, option2 = {option2}");
    }
}
```

Comment: your code shows how to use appsettings.json values directly from API controllers. But the questions is about accessing those values in class library.

Comment: Then you inject IOptions<MyOptions> inside your class? How do you instanciate your class?

Comment: Right, instead of the controller taking the options from Dependency Injection, just modify the class in the library to do that.

Comment: To modify the web application project is not an option for me. Is there a possibility to get the appsettings.json without implement some code in the web application project? I think my problem can also be solved if I can get the wwwroot path of my application from the class library. Is there any way?